# Adjusting an example on RRT (Q.8 on pg.404 of Royden).

Tags: normed-spaces

Here is the question:

Give an example of a measure space $(X, \mathfrak{M}, \mu)$ for which the Riesz Representation Theorem does extend to the case $p=\infty.$

**Here is a trial for a solution:**

Taking X to be a single point, call it $x_{0}$ . So $L^\infty(X,\mu)$ consists of the space of all bounded measurable functions $f : X \to \mathbb{R}$. 
The example is the space consisting of one point $X = \{x\}$ with the counting measure $\mu$, then we want to prove that the dual of $L^\infty equals L^1$. Now we want to satisfy the requirements of Riesz RT statement  in Royden "Real analysis 4th edition":

$p=\infty$ and $q = 1$ the conjugate of $p$. every function $f$ in $L^1(\{x\}, \mu )$ will be a constant function say $c$ . Also, since by definition  $L^\infty(X,\mu)$ consists of the space of all essentially bounded measurable functions $f : X \to \mathbb{R}$ then every $g \in L^\infty(X,\mu)$ will be a constant function, say $ g=c' .$ Now by Riesz RT  we know that for $f \in L^1(\{x\}$ the linear functionals on $L^\infty(X,\mu)$ are those of the form $T_f(g)= \int_X f(x) g(x) d\mu(x)$, $ \forall g \in L^{\infty}(X,\mu)$  and $T_{f}: L^{\infty}(X,\mu) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}.$\

Now,we need to construct a function$ f \in L^1(X,\mu)$ such that $T_f(g)= \int_X f(x) g(x) d\mu(x)$ for all $g \in L^\infty(X,\mu)$ is onto. since the integral in our case will give us 2 constants times the $\mu (\{x\})$ which is 1. then our function can be any constant function say $f = c/d$ where $d$ is the constant representing the function $g.$

**But we received these comments:**

you need to start with a linear dual say $S$ (as the book named it) on $L^{\infty}$, then construct $f\in L^1$ and finally show that $S=T_f.$

**My Questions:**

1-In the proof of RRT, we used Radon Nikodym derivative, what will we do in our case instead of this?

2-Could anyone help me adjust the above trial according  to include the proof of onto?

Comment: In question 1, are you saying this because the measure space $L^\infty(X,\mu)$ is not $\sigma$-finite?

Comment: No @Math1000 we are choosing the counting measure which is $\sigma-$finite ….. I am just trying to mimic the proof in the book but I am getting confused in some steps.

Comment: You're massively overthinking this.  It is an absolutely direct proof to show that all the spaces $L^p(\{x\})$ and their duals are isometric with $ \mathbb{R} $.  No need for any machinery.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think there is a need to try and mimic a complicated proof since your measure space is incredibly simple.

So we have $X = \{x\}$ and $\mu$ is simply the counting measure. First, we have to show that if $T : L^\infty(X) \to \mathbb{C}$ is a continuous linear functional. Then observe that
$$
T(f)=\int_X fg\,\mathrm{d}\mu
$$
where $g(x) = T(\mathbf{1})$ which is clearly in $L^1(X)$. To see that the above inequality is true, we first note that every function in $L^\infty(X)$ is simply a constant multiple of $\mathbf{1}$. Therefore, for any $f\in L^\infty(X)$ we have $f \equiv \lambda\mathbf{1}$ where $\lambda = f(x)$ is a constant. Therefore
$$
T(f) = T(\lambda\mathbf{1}) = \lambda T(\mathbf{1}) = \lambda g(x) =f(x)g(x) = \int_X fg \,\mathrm{d}\mu.
$$
Note that the second equality comes from linearity of $T$.

Conversely, let $g$ be a function in $L^1(X)$. Then it is clear that
$$
T(f) \overset{def}{=} \int_X fg\,\mathrm{d}\mu
$$
is a continuous linear functional. Linearity follows from the linearity of the integral. Continuity holds since
$$
|T(f)| = \left\lvert\int_X fg\,\mathrm{d}\mu\right\rvert
=\left\lvert f(x) g(x) \right\rvert = |g(x)|\cdot |f(x)| = |g(x)|\cdot ||f||_{L^\infty(X)}.
$$
So, for the constant $C = |g(x)| < \infty$, we have $T(f)\leq C||f||_{L^\infty(X)}$ which shows that $T$ is continuous.

Note: You could also note that $L^p(X)$ is the same space with for any $1\leq p \leq \infty$. Since the Riesz representation theorem holds for $p=2$, it must hold for all $1\leq p \leq \infty$.

Comment: Where is your proof that $T$ is onto ? at which part it starts?

Comment: Does not this show that if $T : L^\infty(X) \to \mathbb{C}$ is a continuous linear functional. Then observe that
$$
T(f)=\int_X fg\,\mathrm{d}\mu
$$ require the proof of Onto?

Comment: The "conversely" part shows that it "onto". I am not assuming $T$ is a continuous linear functional. I am defining $T$ by the integral and showing that is is indeed a continuous linear functional