# Understanding a step in the proof of RRT for the dual of $L^p(X,\mu)$ on pg.402.(Royden "Real Analysis" 4th edition )

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, measure-theory, normed-spaces, riesz-representation-theorem

Here is the step that I do not understand:

> [image]

Should not the equality before the last contains a power of $p$ over the sum and an integral sign according to the definition of p-norm , or maybe I do not understand how it comes from its preceding one, could anyone help me understand this please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $F$ is a measurable set, then $\|\chi_F\|_p^p = \int \chi_F^p \, d\mu = \int \chi_F \, d\mu = \mu(F)$ because $\chi_F^p = \chi_F$.

The context of your picture is missing, but if I presume that $E_1,E_2,\ldots$ are disjoint sets whose union is $E$, then $\chi_E - \sum_{k=1}^n \chi_{E_k} = \chi_{\bigcup_{k=n+1}^\infty E_k}$, from which you obtain the desired equality.

Comment: what about the summation sign?

Comment: Could you please look at this question (if you have time )https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3548137/adjusting-an-example-on-rrt-q-8-on-pg-404-of-royden ?

Comment: Is $\chi_{A \cup B} = \chi_{A} + \chi_{B}$?

Comment: @Mathstupid Yes if $A$ and $B$ are disjoint; no otherwise