# How can I calculate $\infty-$ norm of this quantity in measure theory.?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, measure-theory, normed-spaces

How can I calculate $\infty-$ norm of this quantity in measure theory$\| \sum_{k=n + 1}^{\infty} \chi_{E_{k}}||_{\infty}$?

where $E_{k}'s$ are disjoint and knowing that $$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \sum_{k= n+1}^{\infty} \mu(E_{k}) = 0 \quad(1)$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\|\sum\limits_{k=n+1}^{\infty}\chi_{E_k}\|_{\infty}=1$ if $\mu (E_k) >0$ for some $k >n$ and $0$ otherwise.

Comment: So it is zero for large n?

Comment: No. We can have $\mu(E_k)>0$ for all $n$. @Secretly

Comment: even if I am in a space of one point with counting measure?

Comment: Could you check this question for me please https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3550749/checking-an-example-of-a-monotone-class?

Comment: In that case $E_k$ is empty for all $k$ or all $k$ except one.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3548137/adjusting-an-example-on-rrt-q-8-on-pg-404-of-royden could you please tell me how to prove that T onto in this space?